# expected ')' before '*' token error in c

Tags: c, unix, struct, compiler-errors, linux-device-driver

The following is my .h file

```
  1 typedef int32_t status_t;
  2 typedef u_int16_t pic_id_t;
  3 typedef const char* (*pic_flavor_t) (pic_t *);
  4 typedef status_t (*pic_periodic_t) (pic_t *);
  5 typedef status_t (*pic_get_port_info_t) (pic_t *pic, u_int16_t link,void  *info,boolean *need_update);
  6 
  7 struct pic_
  8 {
  9     u_int16_t   nic_slot;
  10     u_int16_t   pic_slot;
  11     u_int32_t   pic_flags;
  12     pic_id_t    pic_id;
  13     u_int16_t   pic_asic_type;
  14     u_int16_t   pic_firstport;
  15     pic_periodic_t  pic_periodic;
  16     pic_flavor_t    pic_flavor;
  17     pic_get_port_info_t pic_get_port_info;
  18     void *pic_context;
  19 }pic_t;
  20
```

and these are the errors i have got.

```
../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:3: error: expected ')'   before '*' token
../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:4: error: expected ')' before '*' token
../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:5: error: expected ')' before '*' token
../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:15: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pic_periodic_t'
```

I am trying to create a new .h file for my .c file. Here I am including definitions of a few structures required in my .c file
I'm unable to tackle these errors.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work

```
typedef struct pic_ pic_t;
typedef int32_t status_t;
typedef u_int16_t pic_id_t;
typedef const char* (*pic_flavor_t) (pic_t *);
typedef status_t (*pic_periodic_t) (pic_t *);
typedef status_t (*pic_get_port_info_t) (pic_t *pic, u_int16_t link,void  *info, boolean *need_update);

struct pic_
{
    u_int16_t   nic_slot;
    u_int16_t   pic_slot;
    u_int32_t   pic_flags;
    pic_id_t    pic_id;
    u_int16_t   pic_asic_type;
    u_int16_t   pic_firstport;
    pic_periodic_t  pic_periodic;
    pic_flavor_t    pic_flavor;
    pic_get_port_info_t pic_get_port_info;
    void *pic_context;
};
```

Comment: hey! yes that worked for most of it, but 1 error still remains ../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'boolean'

Comment: @user3409272 Use `bool`, there's no `boolean` type in the kernel.

Comment: @user3409272 Then use an int. Though bool should be in the linux/types.h header

Comment: @user3409272 I had that error too, but assumed that you had a typedef for `boolean` somewhere since boolean is not one of the standard types. You can fix the error with `typedef int boolean;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pic_t` in:

`typedef const char* (*pic_flavor_t) (pic_t *);`

but you ahave defined `pic_t` type after this.

```
struct pic_
{
    ...
}pic_t;
```

So `pic_t` is not available/not known to compiler at this instant (at line #3).

To remove the error, declare this structure before using `pic_t` type.

Ah! You also need to `typedef` the `struct` to `pic_t` not make it as an structure object.

Well it is better explained with code in *user3386109*'s answer.

Comment: but if i define 
    pic_id_t pic_id
before
    typedef const char* (*pic_flavor_t) (pic_t *);

then it will again look for a definition!

Comment: `pic_id_t` is different from `pic_t`.

Comment: so should i first write the structure
and then  pic_id_t pic_id

Comment: I have declared the structure
and then used pic_t
gives me the same error!